# Which eclipse should I get to work with Java, C, Bash and Perl?

Tags: java, c, eclipse, perl, bash

I'm using eclipse to work on a project with portions written in Java, C, Perl, and bash. Which [version of eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/?osType=linux) should I get for this? I'm currently using 3.5-CDT+perl-plugin and would really like better Java handling with out loosing the C. What plugin should i add for java?

- How does Eclipse handle multi-language projects? when I hit "new project" what do I click?
- can I add a new language to an existing project?
- is there some other IDE that handles multi language projects?

Answer (score 2):

Once you start adding plugins, the Eclipse that you start with doesn't matter. They just happen to provide commonly used sets of plugins prebundled - it's the same core Eclipse under the hood. Whenever I've worked with Eclipse, I've always started with Eclipse Classic and added the plugins that I want to use.

As far as multilanguage projects, I can't address that. I've never used Eclipse (or any other IDE) for multilanguage projects. I've used NetBeans with projects of different languages, but each project was of a particular language.

Comment: That's personal preference - search around the plugin repositories to find plugins that look good, install them, and check them out. Eclipse Classic comes with Java built in, so I've never had to install Java plugins. I've only added things like the C/C++ plugin on top of Eclipse Classic.

Answer (score 2):

For perl, try using the Epic plugin.  Update site: http://www.epic-ide.org/updates

The nice thing about eclipse is that whatever "version" you pick, you can add the updates from other versions (usually) without too many problems.  Pick the version you use the most features of, then go back and add additional plugins as desired.

Comment: The best way to decide if you like something is to try it. If you are unsure of the java, install a java "version" then add C/C++ plugins to it.  Easy enough to add a plugin, try it out, and if you don't like it remove it.

Comment: found the JDT plugin in the main plugin souce thing :) 
Still cant seem to get it to index both java and C code in the same project

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "index"  To add a new plugin navigate help->install new software.  Then on the "work with" dropdown select the Eclipse repository. Select "Programming Languages" then choose away.

Answer (score 1):

The best Eclipse is the one that installs the cleanest on your current OS setup.  Most of the Eclipse issues I've had have had less to do with the language (the exception being PHP) and more to do with my underlying OS.  That said, I haven't even had those issues in a couple of years.